# When modern time measurement first appeared and who invented it?

Tags: time-keeping

My son asked me, how people knew that an hour is an hour before they invented the clock. Reading through [History of timekeeping devices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_timekeeping_devices) on Wikipedia and also [Hour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hour) it became apparent to me, that there was hours of different length in the history until "more accurate current clock" was invented.

If I would have to guess, the first attempts at this would not have given the modern measure of hour anyway, surely there were a few iterations until we settled on the Hour as we know it.

So I would like to know, when people started to use modern hour, and how they arrived to this exact definition of hour, and who was the key people making that happen (if known).

If no precise answer can be given, I'll settle for date ranges.

Comment: Actually, the hour -- and the second -- did become "fixed" in length only when atomic clocks were invented. (GMT defined the second as 1/86400th of a full rotation of the earth, and the rotation time differs, hence the leap seconds in UTC.)

Comment: Related: http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/28957/why-of-all-units-is-time-standard

Comment: @SJuan76, yeah, it's an excellent answer, also linked in the "Related" sidebar on the right.

Comment: As I recall, the Romans divided daylight into 12 hours; as a result the hours varied in length from season to season.  The French tried decimal hours. I suspect that @Alex nailed it with Maskelyne's Nautical Almanac, specifically with [ephemeris time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeris_time).

Comment: @DevSolar: the hour (and the second) were fixed long before the atomic clock invention: by the Sun and stars motion in the sky. We just found it convenient to fix them DIFFERENTLY.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happened gradually and no specific person or date can be stated.
Ancients divided day into equal parts and night into equal parts. So day and night hours were unequal. Of course they realized this. To measure time in the ancient world, there were sundials and water clocks. In the Hellenistic times there were sophisticated water clocks showing unequal hours during the day and night.
With the invention of mechanical clocks, gradually people started to measure time
by mechanical clocks, but this was a slow process. They begin to spread in 14th century, and first ones were tower clocks in the cities. I suppose in the villages, people still used Sun and unequal hours. The standard of clocks was
based on the revolutions of Sun (one full revolution=24 hours).

However, astronomers realized very long ago (in the ancient times) that revolutions of Sun are also not equal: even if you divide day+night (one complete revolution of Sun) into equal parts, these hours will be unequal because of the equation of time (see "equation of time" in Wikipedia).
So the time unit should be based on the revolutions of stars, which is more uniform.

For people other than astronomers, 
this was clearly realized and described only in the middle of 18th century,
with the publication and use of the [Nautical Almanac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Nautical_Almanac) by Nevil Maskelyne.
Again attempts were made to produce sophisticated mechanical clocks which would
show "true" solar time, that is unequal hours. Only with the spread of precise
pocket watches, people started using "equal hours" defined astronomically, as the "mean solar time", that is the revolutions of the starry sky was taken as the standard.

In the end of 19th century scientists realized that any hours defined astronomically are also slightly unequal. It was J. C. Maxwell who first proposed to base the definition of time units on physical processes (frequency of certain radiation) instead of astronomy. His proposal was adopted in the beginning of 20s century. So the modern definition of hour is not related to the
revolutions of the Earth at all, and the hour is defined as 3600 seconds, and the second, the fundamental time unit, is defined as "the duration of 9 192 631 770 periods of the radiation corresponding to the transition between the two hyperfine levels of the ground state of the cesium 133 atom". The final refinement of this definition, specifying the conditions under which this radiation has to be measured was established in 1999, if you wish a date.

Of course the corrections made in 20th century are too small to concern our daily life. So for the hour used in daily life, the standard is a watch, and 
it spread slowly with the spread of non-expensive watches in the beginning of 20s century.

The described process can be summarized as follows: people use some natural process which is thought to be uniform, to measure time. With the development of knowledge, they discover that the process is in face not exactly uniform. They find a new process, which is first used by scientists, but then its use gradually spreads. And this story repeats and lasts as long as our civilization lasts.

Comment: OP asked specifically about "modern" time measurement. I the end of your first paragraph and the second paragraph answer the question.

Comment: It depends:-) The last change in the standard happened in 1999, so it is rather the third paragraph from the end. All depends on what is really meant by "modern time measurement". In science or in daily life.

Comment: In modern daily life, some of us use mechanical watches, some electronic, and some use time signals transmitted from atomic clock. But the first two are checked and adjusted by atomic clock.

Comment: I think you mean "the **last** two" - unless your mechanical watch is way more fancy than any I've seen.

Comment: I use a good non-expensive mechanical watch made in 1960s. I adjust it once a week from  my computer, which means from  the atomic clock signals transmitted by Internet.

Comment: It's just that now, clock is the part of our daily life, we get up by the clock, we go to school by the clock, we meet out friends by the clock. Today they are everywhere and we cannot imagine our life without them. So If I read your answer correctly this started at the beginning of 20th century. Which means in 19th most of the population was content by measuring time by daylight (hey John, let's meet tomorrow by this same tree when  the shadow of this branch starts crossing the road), that's how a dialog could go between two peasants from different villages. Right?

Comment: @Andrew Savinykh: Right. And for this reasons large factories, at least in Russia has "whistles", sirens, which made a signal at the beginning of working day. Workers were not expected to have watches.